# Changing privoxy configuration depending on time

Tags: privoxy

I'm trying to use privoxy for parental control.

What I want is blocking sites (blacklisting) depending on what time it currently is. I.e. No youtube videos from 5:00 am to 8:00 am.

As far as I've seen, the privoxy configuration doesn't allow this kind of rules. I am willing to hack it with a cron-jobs. The question would then be:
What is the recommended way to do this?

- Is there a API?
- Should I use curl to the rescue?
- Hack the config-files and force-reload the service?

I'm sure I'm not the first one trying this, but I struggle finding anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `privoxy` manpage says:

> Note that unlike other daemons Privoxy does not need to be made aware
>   of config file changes by SIGHUP -- it will detect them automatically.

That makes it easy; I would simply go for the cronjob way.  Create `/etc/privoxy-kids` and `/etc/privoxy-adults`; symlink to `/etc/privoxy` according to your favorite schedule.  Ensure your cronjob runs every minute, as a computer turned on at 5:30pm will obviously not run the 5:00pm job.

Caveat emptor: there are so many ways to circumvent a scheme like this (booting off a USB key, using a browser configured without proxy configuration, using http://youtu.be/ which you forgot to include in your blacklist, and so on...) — just ask any of your friends who has to work behind a restricted firewall at the office :)

Comment: Pretty neat. I'm going to try that. Thanks :)